# How to Resize scrollview?

Tags: android, resize, scrollview

I have some `ImageButton` in top of the screen and one `Scrollview` below them.
( XML is `RelativeLayout` )
I want to resize `Scrollview` where is it.
I use this code:

```
scrollview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200)) ;
```

`Scrollview` resize,but it move to top of the screen.
I want resize `ScrollView` in place it is.
I don't want it move to top.
What code do I use?

Full XML and JavaCodes are here:

[p30droid.com/Thread-تغییر-اندازه-اسکرول-ویو-و-imagebutton-و-button](http://p30droid.com/Thread-%D8%AA%D8%BA%DB%8C%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B3%DA%A9%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%88-%D9%88-imagebutton-%D9%88-button)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button11"
 android:layout_width="140dp"
 android:layout_height="65dp"
 android:text="تغییر سایز" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
 android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


 <WebView
 android:id="@+id/webView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#ffffff" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not able to see you XML file

Answer (score 1):

Made one new 'style' for your scrollBar and later import on your XML file, for example:

**/res/drawable/scroll_vertical.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#9a9a9a" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <size android:width="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**principal XML**

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_vertical" >
```